# How to generate junit xml test report in Karate Api Automation with npm?

Tags: karate

I have gone through Karate Api Automation with node ([karatelabs/karate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@karatelabs/karate?activeTab=readme)). When we execute, it generates an html report which is pretty cool..

But, I need to generate an junit xml report, which can be integrated with azure pipelines. Please share the needful insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this part of the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#output-format

So for karate-npm, something like this should work, where `test.js` is your "entry point":

```
npm run test -f junit:xml path/to/your/tests
```

Comment: Its working with above command. Thank You...